# Where does java stderr go?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, stderr

I would like to know, where does java stderr standardly go?

I know I can change the stderr using System.setErr, which 'Reassigns the "standard" error output stream.', but I dont know, which one is "standard".

I would like to specify my question more:
I have C++ library that I use in java (jni). The problem is that it appears that I cannot see output to stderr, that comes from my C++ library. I call assert () in C++ library and don't see the output in console, when I run the java api that uses the library.

Comment: Did you try System.stderr.writeln( "I'm Here" )?  What did you see?

Answer (score 14):

It goes to the standard error stream of the process, whatever that's set up to be.

- If you run the application from a console, it will probably write to the console as well.
- In a GUI, standard out/err are often dropped, i.e. the output is lost.
- In a service (e.g. a web server) the standard error/output is usually captured in a rotated log file somewhere, but it entirely depends on the service.

Most platforms allow you to redirect the standard error stream somewhere else (e.g. to a text file).

The idea of System.setErr is to allow you to *not* use the standard error stream of the process itself, but change it so that calls to `System.err.println` etc go to the given stream.

Answer (score 3):

By default System.err is the console, just like System.out.

Answer (score 2):

File descriptor 2 of the caller. Where it goes from there — depends on the caller.
On console, you can redirect it somewhere else, like for example:

```
java Example 2>> errors.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just written a little test program that does a `System.err.println` and it would appear to be output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

This should go to java.io.FileDescriptor.err
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.err),128),true));
```

Answer (score -1):

The standard error output stream goes to the console. This stream is already open and ready to accept output data.

See the [java sun api](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#err) for further details.